# spring form vs html form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am learning spring form. I wonder what is the point of using spring tag library to create the form. For example below is the code using the tag library in the jsp file

```
   <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm">
        <form:label path="username">Username</form:label><br />
        <form:input path="username" /><br />
        <br />
        <form:label path="name">Name:</form:label><br />
        <form:input path="name" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form:form>
```

When I use "view source" in the browser for the loaded form, the corresponding html is

```
    <form id="userForm" action="/spring-forms/user/add" method="post"><label for="username">Username</label><br />
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value=""/><br />
        <br />
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""/><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form></body>
```

So what happens if I simply write the html version directly rather than using the tag library. Will they achieve exactly the same thing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The spring form is basically a wrapper that gives you easier accessibility to set the value of the form elements using spring objects.

Comment: I know the spring form function of binding object property with form input. In the example that I gave in the question, when I replace the tag lib form with html form, the binding still works! That is what puzzles me

Comment: Do you have any evidence for that claim?